# Unable to mutably borrow the contents inside a RefCell, even after the scope of the previous mutable borrow has ended

Tags: rust

Consider the following bit of code

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

type NodeRef = Rc<RefCell<_Node>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct _Node {
    id: usize,
    data: Option<NodeRef>,
    edges: Vec<NodeRef>,
}

impl _Node {
    fn add(&mut self, other: NodeRef) {
        println!("at {}", self.id);

        self.data = match self.data.take() {
            Some(current_data) => {
                {
                    let mut current_data_raw = current_data.borrow_mut();
                    current_data_raw.id += other.borrow().id;
                }
                Some(current_data)
            }
            None => Some(Rc::clone(&other)),
        };

        for e in &self.edges {
            e.borrow_mut().add(Rc::clone(&other));
        }

        println!("done {}", self.id);
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node(NodeRef);

impl Node {
    fn new(id: usize) -> Node {
        Node(Rc::new(RefCell::new(_Node {
            id,
            data: None,
            edges: vec![],
        })))
    }

    fn add_edge(&self, other: &Node) {
        self.0.borrow_mut().edges.push(Rc::clone(&other.0));
    }

    fn add(&self, other: Self) {
        self.0.borrow_mut().add(other.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Node::new(0);
    let b = Node::new(1);
    let c = Node::new(2);
    let d = Node::new(3);
    let e = Node::new(4);
    let f = Node::new(5);

    d.add_edge(&a);
    d.add_edge(&b);

    e.add_edge(&b);
    e.add_edge(&c);

    f.add_edge(&d);
    f.add_edge(&e);

    f.add(Node::new(6));
}
```

The output generated on running this is

```
at 5
at 3
at 0
done 0
at 1
done 1
done 3
at 4
at 1
thread 'main' panicked at 'already mutably borrowed: BorrowError', src/libcore/result.rs:1009:5
```

This creates a graph of the form

```
F--E--A 
 \  \
  \   B
   \ /
    D
     \ 
      C
```

I am trying to propagate a value through the entire graph, so it starts from F, and goes to E and D. From E it goes to A and B without any error. Then from D, the runtime panics saying the `RefCell` constraint for mutable borrows has been broken.

It seems that it is considering the mutable borrow from the previous invocation of the callback with B, however, the mutable borrow (`current_data_raw`) inside `_Node::add` has a limited scope, and after the scope ends, I should be allowed to mutably borrow the value again. From the output, when the function is called for node B for the second time, the entire first invocation of the function and not just the mutable borrow scope has exited.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses a leading underscore to indicate that a variable or type is *unused*. That's not the case here, so you should not name your type `_Node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing here?

Your algorithm is broken. You can see this by adding this debugging code inside of the `Some` arm of the match:

```
{
    let a = current_data.borrow();
    let b = other.borrow();

    assert_ne!(a.id, b.id);
}
```

This fails:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'assertion failed: `(left != right)`
  left: `6`,
 right: `6`', src/main.rs:23:25
```

You are trying to borrow the *exact same node* twice at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! realized need to explicitly clone on the `None` branch for individual nodes to have independent `data`